# How to use where clause with local variable without passing a parameter in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I joined 2 tables and I want to display document_name from parent table(document_control_reviews) whose ID is currently posted in a child table (initial_approvals). The foreign key that holds the child document is 3.

If I hardcode the query with the ID = 3, I get the correct result just for testing purposes. But I want the documents to be display dynamically using $id instead of 3.

1. This hardcode test works fine when I use 3 as ID:

   ```
    public function initial_approval(){
         $approval_files = DB::table('document_control_reviews')
                      ->leftJoin('initial_approvals', 'initial_approvals.document_control_review_id', '=', 'document_control_reviews.id')
                      ->leftJoin('files', 'document_control_reviews.file_id', '=', 'files.id')
                      ->select('document_control_reviews.*', 'initial_approvals.*', 'files.*')
                      ->where('initial_approvals.document_control_review_id', '=', 3)
                      ->get();
    }
   ```
2. But I need a dynamic ID which is a local variable $id (as showed below):

   ```
    public function initial_approval(){
         $id = 3 //hardcoded. Here is where I'm stuck.
         $docId = DocumentControlReview::find($id);
         $approval_files = DB::table('document_control_reviews')
                      ->leftJoin('initial_approvals', 'initial_approvals.document_control_review_id', '=', 'document_control_reviews.id')
                      ->leftJoin('files', 'document_control_reviews.file_id', '=', 'files.id')
                      ->select('document_control_reviews.*', 'initial_approvals.*', 'files.*')
                      ->where('initial_approvals.document_control_review_id', '=', $id)
                      ->get();
    }
   ```

   3. This is what I don't want. I dont need to pass any parameter. I don't need any argument in the method call.

   ```
    public function initial_approval($id){
         $approval_files = DB::table('document_control_reviews')
                      ->leftJoin('initial_approvals', 'initial_approvals.document_control_review_id', '=', 'document_control_reviews.id')
                      ->leftJoin('files', 'document_control_reviews.file_id', '=', 'files.id')
                      ->select('document_control_reviews.*', 'initial_approvals.*', 'files.*')
                      ->where('initial_approvals.document_control_review_id', '=', $id)
                      ->get();
    }
   ```

Comment: Q: can you please explain why? and where that id comes from, where this method is located ecc ecc

Comment: The id is the primary key of document_control_reviews table which is posted into initial_approvals table as document_control_review_id (foreign key).

Comment: maybe `'document_control_reviews.id'`?

Comment: document_control_reviews.id does not display anything. It leaves the page blank.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code won't work the way you intend to because here id is a collection not an integer.

```
$id = DB::table('document_control_reviews')->select('id')->get();
```

You think id will be an integer like `$id = 3` but in fact here `$id = Collection({"id"=>3},...)` **get()** always return a collection.
What you are trying to do is unclear please elaborate with an example.

Comment: I just need a dynamic ID so that I get resources based on that ID. For example: if you pass an ID as parameter like initiaiLapproval($id) and you will retrieve it like so: $id = InitialApproval::find($id)->get(); I need to achieve something like this but I don't want the $id to be passed as parameter.

Comment: @LawrenceEBosumbe Did you make sure **$id** was an integer (with a `var_dump($id)` ) ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I simply use the where clause in my query where the child ID is a positive integer. And I get exactly what I wanted in this code below:

```
$approval_files = DB::table('document_control_reviews')
                      ->leftJoin('initial_approvals', 'initial_approvals.document_control_review_id', '=', 'document_control_reviews.id')
                      ->select('initial_approvals.*', 'document_control_reviews.*')
                      ->where('initial_approvals.id', '>', 0)
                      ->get();
```